# Unable to open attachments in Windows Live Mail 2009 (Build 14.0.8117,0416)

Tags: windows-vista

I use Windows Live Mail 2009 (Build `14.0.8117.0416`), and it is running on Windows Vista Ultimate 32-bit. If I receive an email message that has an attachment, and I double click to open this attachment, nothing happens. Regardless of the file type of the attachment, nothing happens. If I right click and choose `Open` nothing happens either.

[A Microsoft help article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Why-cant-I-view-an-attachment-in-Windows-Mail) says to do the following to enable access to blocked attachments:

1. Open Windows Mail by clicking the `Start` button , clicking `All Programs`, and then clicking `Windows Mail`.
2. Click the `Tools` menu, and then click `Options`.
3. Click the `Security` tab, clear the `Do not allow attachments to be saved or opened that could potentially be a virus` check box, and then click `OK`.

But I do not have a Tools, Options, Security tab, so am unable to use the MS suggestion

I do not receive 'dangerous' attachments, but need to receive attachments as part of my job.

Could anyone assist me by finding a way around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What type of attachment?

You have to unhide the menu bar, left click on the icon at the top right, select "show menu bar"

[image]

Comment: By pressing the `Alt` key, the menu bar will also be revealed.